# vb.net SQL query works in SQL Server Management Studio but not in program

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, tableadapter

I've got some SQL code:

```
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fromAcctId AS INTEGER,
    @toAcctId As INTEGER,
    @fromProfitId AS INTEGER,
    @toProfitId AS INTEGER,
    @yearId AS INTEGER,
    @period AS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        a.acctid, a.acctno, a.acctseg1, a.descr, a.prftctrid, 
        p.periodno, p.periodamt, p.periodpqty, p.periodaqty, p.mktvalue
    INTO 
        #TEMP
    FROM 
        glacct as a 
    LEFT JOIN 
        glpertot as p on a.acctid = p.acctid
    WHERE 
        CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) >= @fromAcctId 
        AND CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) <= @toAcctId 
        AND a.prftctrid >= @fromProfitId 
        AND a.prftctrid <= @toProfitId
        AND p.periodno = @period 
        AND p.yearid = @yearId
    ORDER BY 
        a.acctid;

    INSERT INTO #TEMP
       SELECT 
          a.acctid, a.acctno, a.acctseg1, a.descr, a.prftctrid
       FROM 
          glacct as a
       WHERE 
          CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) >= @fromAcctId 
          AND CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) <= @toAcctId 
          AND a.prftctrid >= @fromProfitId 
          AND a.prftctrid <= @toProfitId
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT acctid FROM #TEMP WHERE acctid = a.acctid)

    SELECT * FROM #TEMP ORDER BY acctno
 END
```

This code works in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, works in the VB.NET table adapter data preview, but fails in the actual program.

The mode of failure is:

```
Table-name = table-adapter.getdata(parameters)
```

returns a data table with information that is accurate for the first 6 columns (account id, account number, account segment 1, account description, profit center id), but the rest of the columns are wildly inaccurate (either null or REALLY wrong).

However, on some queries (e.g. searching for accounts 000000 to 999999, with profit center 1 to 4, a yearid of 8, and a period of 8) will return accurate results.

I'm wondering if you guys could point me in a general direction as to what could be wrong.

Also, I apologize if there is another topic on this subject, but most of the search results were either not applicable (C#, Delphi, etc...) or were talking about queries that were written out as string inside a vb.net program and then passed to a server.

Also, I realize the code is bad, and any pointers on how I could make it better would be a appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to tell you what might be wrong with your VB.NET code, since you've included absolutely zero lines of VB.NET code. You've also included zero sample data, zero results that you obtained, zero information about the input you're providing to the procedure, or any other information that we can use to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you try to use a table variable? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: What denotes "accurate" vs "inaccurate"?

Comment: In short, pls mentioned full VB.NEt code. & Result of SQL Server after executing same query.

Comment: @bdn02 's suggestion of using a table variable fixed the issue. I'm not sure why that worked, but it works and that is good enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to solve this, I would use a SqlDataReader.  Not sure why you staged the data to a #TEMP table, the LEFT JOIN should directly return all of the needed records.  Yes, you will need to write out your query as a string.  It would have been helpful to know what type of output you are looking for ... this will simply write to the console.  NOTE: I did not do much of anything to trap errors and/or verify parameters are legitimate values, that will be up to you.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Sub GetData(FromAcctId As Integer, ToAcctId As Integer, FromProfitId As Integer, ToProfitId As Integer, YearId As Integer, Period As Integer)
  Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
  Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
  Dim StrSQL As String = ""
  Dim d1 As SqlDataReader

  Try
    ' Next line, change 4 XX-values to your environment
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Server=XXServerName;Database=XXDatabaseName;User ID=XXUserName;Password=XXPassword;Persist Security Info=True"
    Cmd.Connection = Conn

    Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromAcctId", FromAcctId)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toAcctId", ToAcctId)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromProfitId", FromProfitId)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toProfitId", ToProfitId)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@period", YearId)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@period", Period)

    ' The vbCrLf can be removed, that's left-over from my utility
    StrSQL = "SELECT " & vbCrLf & _
        "    a.acctid, a.acctno, a.acctseg1, a.descr, a.prftctrid, " & vbCrLf & _
        "    p.periodno, p.periodamt, p.periodpqty, p.periodaqty, p.mktvalue" & vbCrLf & _
        "  FROM glacct as a " & vbCrLf & _
        "    LEFT OUTER JOIN  glpertot AS p" & vbCrLf & _
        "      ON a.acctid = p.acctid" & vbCrLf & _
        "  WHERE " & vbCrLf & _
        "    (CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) >= @fromAcctId )" & vbCrLf & _
        "      AND (CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) <= @toAcctId)" & vbCrLf & _
        "      AND (a.prftctrid >= @fromProfitId)" & vbCrLf & _
        "      AND (a.prftctrid <= @toProfitId)" & vbCrLf & _
        "      AND ((p.periodno = @period) OR (p.periodno IS NULL))" & vbCrLf & _
        "      AND ((p.yearid = @yearId) OR (p.yearid IS NULL))" & vbCrLf & _
        "  ORDER BY " & vbCrLf & _
        "    a.acctno"
    Cmd.CommandText = StrSQL
    Conn.Open()
    d1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If d1.HasRows Then
      ' optionally, you can make the delimeter StrDelim = "," to output comma-seperated data
      Dim StrDelim As String = vbTab
      Console.WriteLine("acctid" & StrDelim & "acctno" & StrDelim & "acctseg1" & StrDelim & "descr" & StrDelim & "prftctrid" & StrDelim & "periodno" & StrDelim & "periodamt" & StrDelim & "periodpqty" & StrDelim & "periodaqty" & StrDelim & "mktvalue")
      Console.WriteLine("------" & StrDelim & "------" & StrDelim & "--------" & StrDelim & "-----" & StrDelim & "---------" & StrDelim & "--------" & StrDelim & "---------" & StrDelim & "----------" & StrDelim & "----------" & StrDelim & "--------")
      Do While d1.Read
        Console.WriteLine(d1("acctid") & StrDelim & d1("acctno") & StrDelim & d1("acctseg1") & StrDelim & d1("descr") & StrDelim & d1("prftctrid") & StrDelim & d1("periodno") & StrDelim & d1("periodamt") & StrDelim & d1("periodpqty") & StrDelim & d1("periodaqty") & StrDelim & d1("mktvalue"))
      Loop
    End If
  Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("ErrorInfo, StrSQL: " & StrSQL & vbCrLf & "Message: " & ex.ToString())
  Finally
    Conn.Close()
  End Try
End Sub
```

Then for "accounts 000000 to 999999, with profit center 1 to 4, a yearid of 8, and a period of 8" you would call this Sub:

```
  GetData(000000, 999999, 1, 4, 8, 8)
```

(103m)

Comment: Not the left does not bring in all the rows.  p in the where breaks the left

Answer (score 0):

First what are you trying to do with the query?
AND p.periodno = @period  in the first where breaks the left
Then in the second you just fill in the left you broke
All you are doing buy splitting it in two is not showing p data out of the second
Try this

```
  SELECT 
        a.acctid, a.acctno, a.acctseg1, a.descr, a.prftctrid, 
        p.periodno, p.periodamt, p.periodpqty, p.periodaqty, p.mktvalue
    FROM 
        glacct as a 
    LEFT JOIN 
        glpertot as p 
         on a.acctid = p.acctid
        and CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) >= @fromAcctId 
        AND CAST(a.acctid AS INTEGER) <= @toAcctId 
        AND a.prftctrid >= @fromProfitId 
        AND a.prftctrid <= @toProfitId
    ORDER BY 
        a.acctno;
```

If you want to hide p information then

```
   CASE 
      WHEN (p.periodno = @period AND p.yearid = @yearId) THEN p.periodno 
      else null
   END
   ...
```

If you padded the second with 5 null the existing might work

Comment: The first block of code is supposed to get the entire subset of all accounts that have information in the glpertot table that have an account number within the proper range, a profit center within the proper range, the desired period number, and the correct yearid. The second block of code then adds all the other accounts to the table while leaving the last 5 columns (period number, period amount, period primary quantity, period alternate quantity, market value) as null because those accounts either have no entry in the glpertot table or do not have the right period and year.

Comment: @VerticallyInclined I know what you code does - I am saying it does not doe it very well.  The left join is broken by the where.  And you can deal with reporting null in a case statement as I have shown.